# Filter phone models on android market

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I have a trouble with my application: 
I use MediaPlayer to download audio from my server. For the emulator and the most models all is working fine, but for Motorola Atrix and one Huawei phone the audio is not downloading at all. This happens to remote users leaving comments on google play, so I can't ask them for logs or something like it. Also, I download other data via HttpClient and it downloads ok on listed phones.

So, 2 questions:

1. Why on earth MediaPlayer won't load the media file? What I can do to detect it?
2. How to filter out the phone models causing troubles?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the first question, but you can filter out specific devices in the developer console when you log in to the Android Market/Google Play. Go to your app's page, scroll down to Supported Devices and click Show Devices to get a list of devices that allows you to exclude specific models.